# ldap password policy minimum length is not working

Tags: ldap, openldap, password-policy

I have a working LDAP server. Next added password policy to LDAP server. My password ldif looks like this:

```
dn: cn=MyPolicy,ou=Policies,dc=XXX,dc=XXXX
cn: MyPolicy
objectClass: pwdPolicy
#objectClass: pwdPolicyChecker
objectClass: device
objectClass: top
pwdAttribute: 2.5.4.35
#pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdMaxAge: 7862400
pwdExpireWarning: 6048000
pwdInHistory: 3
pwdCheckQuality: 2
pwdMinLength: 7
pwdMaxFailure: 3
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 300
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
pwdReset: FALSE
```

it is successfully added to my LDAP server. But only Lock out and Lock out duration is working. Password minimum length is not working.

```
   pam configuration
Server side configuration

pam.d/common-auth
auth [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth requisite pam_deny.so
auth required  pam_permit.so

pam.d/common-account
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]  pam_unix.so
account requisite    pam_deny.so
account required     pam_permit.so

pam.d/common-password
password [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512 minlen=8
password requisite  pam_deny.so
password required  pam_permit.so


Client side configuration

pam.d/common-auth
auth [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so null_secure try_first_pass
auth [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth  requisite   pam_deny.so
auth  required    pam_permit.so

pam.d/common-account
account [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so 
account [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so 
account needs pam_deny.so
account required pam_permit.so

pam.d/common-password
password  [success=2 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure sha512
password  [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die] pam_ldap.so try_first_pass
password  requisite  pam_deny.so
password  required   pam_permit.so

ldap.conf
pam_lookup_policy yes
```

Can you please let me know where I am gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 300
```

These attributes are used on failed bind attempts to lock an account

```
pwdMinLength: 7
```

This attribute is only checked when a user (except manager DN) performs a modify password operation on his `userPassword` attribute. It will not lock already created accounts which do not satisfy this rule.

EDIT :

Considering your different comments, try to modify the line in your file `/etc/ldap.conf` :

From :

```
pam_password crypt
```

To :

```
pam_password exop
```

It will modify the password using the extended operation modifypassword and so should trigger the password policy.

Comment: If I try to type wrong password for the user's account three times then the account is locked for 300 sec. It is working fine for me. Only thing is minimum length is not enforced or something while changing password.

Comment: @user3906723 I edited my answer with more informations

Comment: I changed the pam_password to exop but still it is not triggering password policy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OpenLDAP, the password policy overlay is completely bypassed by the ManagerDN. You should never use this yourself: it is only for the OpenLDAP server itself. You need to use another, less privileged but sufficiently priviledged, LDAP account for performing password modifications: preferably, the user's own account.

Comment: I am using user's own account for password modification. But in LDAP account I have given password minimum length as 7. But wen I change a user's password using passwd it is accepting 6 characters but it should accept 7 characters right

Comment: @user3906723 Considering your comment I assume your authenticating your users through PAM on linux system? If so, please provide your pam configuration. Are you sure delegated password management to the LDAP directory in your PAM configuration? Else, it is in your pam module that you have to put the password retrictions

Comment: @Esteban pam configuration                                          
   Server side configuration:: pam.d/common-auth  
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth  requisite pam_deny.so
auth  required pam_permit.so

pam.d/common-account
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so
account requisite  pam_deny.so
account required  pam_permit.so

Comment: @Esteban Client side config::pam.d/common-auth
auth    [success=2 default=ignore] pam_unix.so null_secure try_first_pass
auth    [success=1 default=ignore] pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth    requisite pam_deny.so
auth    required  pam_permit.so
pam.d/common-account
account [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_ldap.so 
account [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so 
account needs pam_deny.so
account required pam_permit.so

Comment: @Esteban Client side config:::pam.d/common-password
password  [success=2 default=ignore]pam_unix.so obscure sha512
password  [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die]     pam_ldap.so try_first_pass
password  requisite  pam_deny.so
password  required  pam_permit.so
ldap.conf
pam_lookup_policy yes

Comment: @user3906723 You should edit your question with the configuration in order for it to be readable ^^. Also, take a look at this tutorial, may be it will give you a hint : http://www.flagword.net/2013/02/openldap-with-tls-ppolicy-and-master-master-replication-on-rhel6-3

Comment: @Esteban I followed that link and found that I have not installed sssd. Maybe I will install this and see if that works. Thanks

Comment: @Esteban I am following the link which you have shared. In that I installed sssd service in ldap server and was configuration I can't find these files pam.d/system-auth files and /nsswitch.conf. In some of the links I found that sssd is installed in client machine not in the server. I am getting confused. Please help me out.

Comment: @Esteban I tried to change in pam.d/common-password                
password sufficient pam_ldap.so
password required pam_unix.so nullok minlen=8 sha512                                                                 But still it is accepting 6 characters when using passwd             Please help me out

Comment: @user3906723 I'm no expert in PAM , but from what I know, configuring pam on you LDAP server is useless, it has to be configured on each computer/server where you need to have your users able to log into. It is this "client" machine that will request the LDAP server

Comment: @Esteban I am not configuring PAM in my LDAP server. I am configuring in client machine where it ll request LDAP server only.